# TFS 2012 Build Server Not Working, Receive HTTP Error Code 500

Tags: build, tfsbuild

We've set up a new TFS 2012 Build Server and we are just not able to get it working. No queued builds show any progress even if the Build Controller and Agent are configured and enabled.

When we click the "Details" link on the Build Configuration node in the TFS Admin Console we get the error "HTTP Code 500: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException".

How do we fix this?

P.S. We've installed on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: That error code is related to a TFS web service that is unable to run. Try the following link that describes the same error (also links to an additional site with workaround details): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/680ca0e8-755b-4f22-9705-f165980a5378/

Comment: Found another link that states the HTTP 500 error can appear when resources are low on the machine: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2013/04/09/error-while-configuring-build-controller-http-code-500-system-servicemodel-serviceactivationexception-quot.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Not multiple host headers but only SSL binding on app tier - tweaked web.config for this. We have build and logs, yippee!